# SQLCMD, PowerShell, BCP tool coded in stored procedure -SQL Server Managed Instance

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am planning to migrate a legacy application which was using SQL Server 2012 to latest SQL Server managed instance on Azure.

But I doubt it will work, because my database has lots of stored procedures which use `SQLCMD` and `BCP` tools.

For example:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

FTP commands, PowerShell copy command which involves actual file storage.

It will execute fine on a standalone Windows machine where we have actual storage like `C:/` or `D:/`

But how it will behave in latest SQL Server Managed Instance on Azure?

Please can you suggest any idea?

Will the same stored procedure code work fine in latest SQL Server Managed Instance on Azure?

Comment: ETL is not a function that belongs inside the database engine.

Answer (score 1):

xp_cmdshell is not supported on [Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server?view=azuresql#stored-procedures-functions-and-triggers).  Either migrate that stuff to a different solution, or use [SQL Server on Azure VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-server-on-azure-vm-iaas-what-is-overview?view=azuresql), which is super easy to set up and operate.